# Buscar um valor específico de um array de acordo com valores de outro array e mostrar o valor de outro campo

Tags: php

Eu tenho dois arrays, um chamado estoque e outro chamado entrada. Ambos possuem os elementos com o mesmo par de chaves. Exemplo:

Estoque:

```
$estoque= array(
    array (
        'tamanho' => '33',
        'quantidade' => '0'
    ),
     array (
        'tamanho' => '34',
        'quantidade' => '0'
    ),
     array (
        'tamanho' => '37',
        'quantidade' => '1'
    ),
     array (
        'tamanho' => '35',
        'quantidade' => '3'
    )
);
```

Entrada:

```
$entrada= array(
    array (
        'tamanho' => '33',
        'quantidade' => '1'
    ),
     array (
        'tamanho' => '34',
        'quantidade' => '3'
    ),
     array (
        'tamanho' => '35',
        'quantidade' => '5'
    ),
     array (
        'tamanho' => '37',
        'quantidade' => '9'
    )
);
```

Só que preciso pegar a quantidade da entrada e inserir no estoque quando os elementos tiverem o mesmo tamanho.
Eu fiz um laço para percorrer o array do estoque, <del>mas não sei como verificar se existe o mesmo tamanho no outro array</del> mas não sei como mostrar o valor da quantidade do elemento encontrado. <del>Eu pensei em fazer dois laços, mas acredito que o PHP deve ter uma função mais apropriada.</del> . Alguém sabe me dizer e como funciona?
Na lógica seria parecido com isso:

```
foreach ($estoque as $key => $produto) {
          if(in_array($produto['tamanho'],array_column($entrada,'tamanho'))){
                echo 'Entrada do tamanho ".$produto['tamanho']." é (mostrar a quantidade do elemento do array de entrada de acordo com o tamanho)';
          }
        }
```

Comment: Vc quer somar os valores em "quantidade"? Na primeira array tem "tamanho => 37 e quantidade => 1", na segunda "tamanho => 37 e quantidade => 9", então ficaria na primeira array "tamanho => 37 e quantidade => 10"?

Comment: Sim. Eu vou até modificar o post. Consegui verificar se existe mas preciso pegar o valor da quantidade da entrada de acordo com a comparação. Ex. Eu achei o tamanho 37 nos dois arrays. Então como pegar o valor da quantidade no array da entrada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, o seguinte código deve resolver o seu problema.

```
foreach ($entrada as $key => $value) {

    if(false !== $key_search = array_search($value['tamanho'], array_column($estoque, 'tamanho'))) {

        $estoque[$key_search]['quantidade'] += $entrada[$key]['quantidade'];
    }
}
```

Para visualizar o resultado:

```
print_r("<pre>");
print_r($estoque);
print_r("</pre>");
```